# Print all permutations of selected length characters with repetition and do not start over after closing the program in CPP

Tags: c++, for-loop, permutation, cartesian-product

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void enumerate(const string& s, int n, string t = "")
{
    if (n == 0)
        cout << t << endl;
    else
    {
        for (char c : s)
            enumerate(s, n - 1, t + c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    enumerate("abc", 5);
}
```

Hi, guys, I wanna make all of the possible permutations of selected length characters but maybe the power is gone or I suddenly close the program or maybe I have to restart my computer so I should open the program again and it starts over so our time and energy will be lost.
also I don't how this type of for loop works (for (char c : s)) so how can I save the progress,
for example, if it's for 100 times that the loop is working save the number 100 in a text file or everything else and after that, if I closed the program for a reason and opened again read the number 100 from the text file and don't start over and continue the loop.

Comment: Check that `n < s.length()` in your `enumerate()` function.

Comment: It seems you want Cartesian product, not permutation.

Comment: Which is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Handling string permutations

C++ has a handy standard library algorithm [`std::next_permutation`](https://devdocs.io/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) which you can use to handle string permutations for you.

### One solution

Below is a brute force approach in which every possible permutation of the larger "parent" string is iterated through, and the first `n` character substring tested for uniqueness. If that child substring is unique, then it is printed and added to the set of "already used" child permutations.

After each iteration you can save the current parent permutation state. You can later pass it to the `print_permutation` function, which will resume permutation calculation from that point. See the implementation below for more details.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

typedef std::function<void(const std::string& masterPerm, const bool finished)> PermutationCallback;

std::string new_master_permutation(std::string&& str) {
  std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
  return str;
}

void print_permutation_if_unused(
  const std::string& childPermutation,
  std::unordered_set<std::string>& childPermsTried
) {
  if (!childPermsTried.contains(childPermutation)) {
    childPermsTried.insert(childPermutation);
    std::cout << childPermutation << '\n';
  }
}

void print_permutations(
  std::string masterPermutation,
  const size_t numCharsInPerm,
  const PermutationCallback& callback
) {
  std::unordered_set<std::string> childPermsTried;
  // Actual constrained length of child permutation strings
  const size_t permutationLength = std::min(masterPermutation.size(), numCharsInPerm);

  do {
    print_permutation_if_unused(masterPermutation.substr(0, permutationLength), childPermsTried);
    callback(masterPermutation, false);
  } while (std::next_permutation(masterPermutation.begin(), masterPermutation.end()));

  callback(masterPermutation, true);
}

int main(void) {
  // Begin with a new permutation, starting with the sorted string "abbc"
  print_permutations(new_master_permutation("bacb"), 3,
    [](const std::string& masterPerm, const bool finished) {
      // Save the master permutation for reference
    }
  );

  // Begin at any midpoint permutation ("bacb"), and calculate the rest.
  print_permutations("bacb", 3, [](const std::string& masterPerm, const bool finished) {
    // Save the master permutation for reference
  });
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that **this implementation is far from optimal.** Execution increases by factorial time with each character added to the master permutation string. Larger child permutation length greatly increases memory use since each unique permutation is stored in a set. However, it does work, and should provide at least a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer and explanation for real,
but there is just a little problem, in line 18 the command .contains is wrong I have tried MinGW c++ 11 and VS compiler but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. `.contains` is part of C++ 20. Replace the conditional with `childPermsTried.emplace(childPermutation) == childPermsTried.end()` and it will work with C++ 11. The `insert` call in line 19 also needs to be changed to `emplace` because insert is part of C++17.